# Haskell - assert a function was called

Tags: haskell, hunit, hspec

Is it possible to verify that a function was called in Haskell HSpec?

Assuming I had two functions **foo** and **bar** that transform my data.

```
foo :: Stuff -> Stuff
bar :: Stuff -> Stuff
```

And I have a function that applies either **foo** or **bar** on **Stuff**  depending on whether it received 'f' or 'b' as its second argument and returns the result of the applied function.

```
apply :: Stuff -> Char -> Stuff
```

And In my tests, I have tested each of the functions foo and bar comprehensively that i would not want to test there effect with in **apply**.

Is it possible for me to verify that a function foo or bar was called? depending on what argument is passed to apply?

Comment: can't you write a `print` or similar statement into the body of `foo` and `bar` to see which one gets called? Which monads have you loaded in?

Comment: I am thinking more in terms of TDD,  asserting using Hspec. Like how we do in OOP/imperative languages like ruby-rspec                       expect(user).to receive(:save) Is such a thing possible in purely functionally language like Haskell?

Comment: if you are purely functional, you shouldn't be able to observe whether you are executing a function or not, or how many times (because invoking function shouldn't have any side effect, and observing that you have executed that is indeed a side effect). I don't know much about ruby-rspec or hspec though, so I'm not sure, however in a purely functional language if you can't distinguish between the two return values, you are actually invoking the same function

Comment: I'm looking through the documentation of hspec right now. Do you have any complete code example on what is that you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks ... I have gotten an Idea. I can test that the right function was called depending on the return values. The transformation on data should be able to report which function was called. Thanks for the hint :-)

Comment: basically if you add metadata to the return value to recognize which one has been called, you are doing a monadic transformation: the monads in haskell do this kind of operation transparently if you use the `do` syntax. If you found an answer and it satisfies you you should write it down here and accept it, for future reference

Comment: Don’t forget that if you found an appropriate solution to your problem you can add an answer to your own question. That way, if someone lands here while looking for a solution to their own problem that might help them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will keep searching until I feel I have a great solution. Then I will share it.

Comment: If you are only using this for debugging and not production code, you could cheat a little and use `Debug.Trace`.

Comment: I am unit testing my code. I am sure the functions are being called ... Its just that i want to unit test the function apply by checking whether it called foo or bar and not by testing it's return since in I already tested that in the tests of foo and bar.

Comment: Surely you *do* want to test the returned value (since that is all you should care about). Basically `foo x = apply x 'f'` for some suitable `x` and the same with bar/y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I'm thinking more TDD, like in an OOP language. Is such a thing possible in Haskell?"

A better question is "is such a thing *necessary* in Haskell?" ;-)

[I realise that is not the question you actually asked. Feel free to ignore this answer.]

In an OO language, we build objects that talk to other objects to get their job done. To test such an object, we build a bunch of fake objects, hook the real object up to the fake ones, run the method(s) we want to test, and assert that it calls faked methods with the expected inputs, etc.

In Haskell, we write *functions*. The only thing a pure function does is take some input, and produce some output. So the way to test that is to just *run* the thing, feeding it known inputs and checking that it returns known outputs. What other functions it calls in the process of doing that doesn't *matter*; all we care about is whether the answer is right.

In particular, the reason we don't usually do this in OOP is that calling some arbitrary method might cause "real work" to happen — reading or writing disk files, opening network connections, talking to databases and other servers, etc. If you're just testing one part of your code, you don't want the test to depend on whether some database is running on a real network server somewhere; you just want to test one little part of your code.

With Haskell, we separate anything that can affect the Real World from stuff that just does data transformations. Testing stuff that just transforms data in memory is delightfully trivial! (Testing the parts of your code that do interact with the Real World is still hard, in general. But hopefully those parts are very small now.)

The Haskell test style of choice seems to be property-based testing. For example, if you've got a function to solve an equation, you write a QuickCheck property that randomly generates 100 equations, and for each one, it checks whether the number returned actually solves the original equation or not. It's a tiny handful of code that automatically tests just about everything you'd ever want to know! (But not quite: You need to make sure that the "randomly" chosen equations actually test all the code paths you care about.)

Comment: I figured that much after having conversations with people who know a lot more about Haskell and functional programming than me ;-).  Thanks for your response, i intended to post a similar answer  but I guess I wouldn't have phrased it as well as you did.

Answer (score 0):

(No exactly Haskell, but close.)

```
fooP = point . foo
-- testable property: forall s. foo s = runIdenity $ fooP s

barP = point . bar
-- similar testable property

fooAndWitness :: Stuff -> Writer String Stuff
fooAndWitness = fooM >> tell "foo"
-- testable property forall s. (foo s, "foo") = runWriter $ fooAndWitness s

barAndWitness :: Stuff -> Writer String Stuff
barAndWitness = barM >> tell "bar"
-- similar testable property

applyOpen :: Pointed p => (Stuff -> p Stuff) -> (Stuff -> p Stuff) -> Stuff -> Char -> p Stuff
applyOpen onF _   x 'f' = onF x
applyOpen _   onB x 'b' = onB x
applyOpen _   _   x _   = point x
-- semi-testable property (must fix p):
-- forall f b s c. let a = applyOn f b s c in a `elem` [f s, b s, point s]
-- In particular, if we choose p carefully we can be, at least stochastically,
-- sure that either f, b, or neither were called by having p = Const [Int], and running several tests
-- where two random numbers are chosen, `f _ = Const $ [rand1]`, and `b _ = Const $ [rand2]`
-- and verifying we get one of those numbers, which could not have been known when applyOpen was written.

applyM = applyOpen fooM barM
-- similar testable property, although but be loose the "rigged" tests for variable f/b, so
-- some of our correctness may have to follow from the definition.

apply = (runIdentity .) . applyM
-- similar testable property and caveat
```

`Pointed` is a type class that fits between Functor and Applicative and provides `point` with the same semantics as `pure` or `return`.  It's only law follows from parametricity: `(. point) . fmap = (point .)`